# how to transfer files using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

is it possible to transfer files using vb.net? Cutting the files from a certain directory and copy it to another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class and its [`Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) method.

Or the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_methods.aspx) class and its [`MoveTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto.aspx) method.

If you want to move whole directories, there are the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory_members.aspx) and [`DirctoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo_members.aspx) classes and their associated [`Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx) and [`MoveTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.moveto.aspx) methods.

With all of the above, if you do want copies, instead of moving files, use the `Copy` and `CopyTo` methods, which work similarly to the `Move` and `MoveTo` methods.

This is applicable to all .NET languages, not only VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_methods.aspx) class has a `MoveTo` method that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Dim dd As New DirectoryInfo(dirname)

```
    For Each ff As FileInfo In dd.GetFiles("*.CSV", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        ff.CopyTo(sentPath + "\Sent\" + SentFolder + "\" & ff.Name, True) '
        If File.Exists(sentPath + "\" & ff.Name) Then
            File.Delete(sentPath + "\" & ff.Name)
        End If

    Next
```